# How to create web, mobile, and desktop apps from a common code base?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, mobile, desktop-application

I want to create an app for the web (all popular browsers), mobile (Android and iOS), and desktop (Windows, MacOS, and Linux). I know that platform-specific code is unavoidable in that case, but I'm searching for an approach that minimizes it.

One approach to what I read is utilizing the JavaScript/TypeScript stack using React (for web), React Native (for mobile), and Electron (for desktop). I know that for example, an alternative to Electron is NW.js. Some people suggest capacitor.js instead of React Native. Also, React Native has support for desktop apps for Windows and MacOS, but it seems not for Linux.

Another approach is the Flutter framework for the Dart language.

What approaches and tech stacks you could suggest for such cross-platform development?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Expo. Note, that if you need some truly native features you have to 'detach' from expo, which is possible later on, but something you may want to avoid from the off. This has become less required over time, the more Expo improves, but just something to note. https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/introduction/